# Longest Common Subsequence in Ocaml

Tags: string, ocaml, lcs

Does someone know how to find the longest common subsequence of a set of strings in Ocaml language?

Comment: there is notihing ocaml-specific here, general algorithm question.

Comment: unfortunately I cannot answer with 'YES' as answers have to be at least 40 characters...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at other questions tagged "lcs", like [Longest common subsequence of 3+ strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057243/longest-common-subsequence-of-3-strings) . Then you should be able to write the code in OCaml.